# Debug Memory Overwrite in MSVC

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, memory, breakpoints

I am currently using MSVC to try to figure out where memory is overwritten. I use a data breakpoint in MSVC with the memory address. It stops when the memory changes and I see the hex values being changed and some low level code in another windows (pop off the list etc).

My question is how to do I get MSVC to stop when the memory is changed BUT instead of showing me the memory hex values to show me the line of C code causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct answer.
When your program is suspended, you can see the Call Stack of each thread of your program, and analyse it.
To see it you show the Threads window:
`Debug->Windows->Threads`.
You chose the thread by double clicking and then look into window Call Stack (`Debug->Windows->Call Stack`) 
Analyse the uppermost functions in that list.